# How to remove bottom white line in dark mode

Tags: android, flutter, darkmode

I am designing an application in flutter for light mode and dark mode. But in dark mode it shows white line in few devices only. Not in all devices. Currently I am testing on OnePlus 6T. Attached a screenshot with white bottom line and without bottom line.

Is it possible to remove this white bottom line from bottom.

[image: OnePlus 6T]

Comment: Have you remove safearea from scacfold?

Comment: Yes.. I have removed safearea.

Comment: Still have same problem?

Comment: Please try to put theme on whole app